# Printf Hex Formatting Leads Wrong Output

Tags: c

I have following C code.

```
char a[] = "\x7f\x80";
printf("0x%02x\n",a[0]);
printf("0x%02x",a[1]);
```

It should print,

```
0x7f
0x80
```

However I'm getting following ?

```
0x7f
0xffffff80
```

What changes I have to make to get the output **0x7f** **0x80**?

Thanks,

Comment: `(unsigned char)a[1]`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I actually tried printf("0x%02x\n",(unsigned)a[0]) .

Comment: You can also do `"0x%02hhx\n"`.

Comment: As Michael said. It is the sign extension during type promotion. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715984/printf-type-promotion-and-sign-extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct types and conversion specifiers:

```
unsigned char a[] = "\x7f\x80";
printf("0x%02hhx\n",a[0]);
printf("0x%02hhx",a[1]);
```

Conversion specifier `x` requires an unsigned type, and the length modifier `hh` is used for `unsigned char`.